# Django: ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field account.UserProfile.user: auth.User

Tags: python, django

Getting this error when running `python manage.py migrate`:

> ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field account.UserProfile.user: auth.User

Steps I did:

**1.** Created project and added new app:

```
$ django-admin.py startproject djdev
$ cd djdev
$ python manage.py startapp account
```

**2.** I added new app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `djdev/settings.py`:

```
...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'account',
)
...
```

**3.** Created a new `UserProfile` model class in `account/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """
    User Profile having one-to-one relations with User
    """
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_profile'
        ordering = ['id']

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, db_column='id_user', related_name='profile')

    mobile_no = models.CharField('Mobile no.', db_column='contact_no_home', max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    address_line_1 = models.CharField('Address Line 1', db_column='contact_address_line_1_home', max_length=140, blank=True, null=True)
    address_line_2 = models.CharField('Address Line 2', db_column='contact_address_line_2_home', max_length=140, blank=True, null=True)

    office_mobile_no = models.CharField('Mobile no.', db_column='contact_no_office', max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    office_address_line_1 = models.CharField('Address Line 1', db_column='contact_address_line_1_office', max_length=140, blank=True, null=True)
    office_address_line_2 = models.CharField('Address Line 2', db_column='contact_address_line_2_office', max_length=140, blank=True, null=True)

    about = models.TextField('About me', blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.CharField('Note', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.name
```

**4.** Started migrating:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations account
$ python manage.py migrate
```

After executing last command `python manage.py migrate` I'm getting this error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: (none)
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, account, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  Applying account.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vinay/python_webapps/django-trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 427, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vinay/python_webapps/django-trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/vinay/python_webapps/django-trunk/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/vinay/python_webapps/django-trunk/django/core/management/base.py", line 337, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/vinay/python_webapps/django-trunk/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 146, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/home/vinay/python_webapps/django-trunk/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 62, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/home/vinay/python_webapps/django-trunk/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 90, in apply_migration
    if self.detect_soft_applied(migration):
  File "/home/vinay/python_webapps/django-trunk/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 134, in detect_soft_applied
    apps = project_state.render()
  File "/home/vinay/python_webapps/django-trunk/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 83, in render
    model=lookup_model
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field account.UserProfile.user: auth.User
```

> NOTE: Django Version I'm using: **1.8.dev20140507130401**

Comment: had no idea syncdb has been deprecated, removing my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is already fixed in the master branch.

**Fixed in commits**:

- https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/8f6dff372b174e772920de6d82bd085f1a74eaf2
- https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/35c2a14a49ac3cb25dcff818b280bf0b4c290287

You can install it until a proper release is built:

```
pip install https://github.com/django/django/zipball/master
```

**Test**:

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Test(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

*Results*

```
[__env] $ ./manage.py makemigrations
  Migrations for 'data':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Test
[__env] $ ./manage.py migrate
  Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
    (... ommited ...)
  Running migrations:
  Applying data.0001_initial... OK
```

Comment: I've updated Django by pulling latest commits and new Django version is `1.8.dev20140509025115`. Now I'm getting this error: `ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field admin.LogEntry.user: auth.User
The missing model matches AUTH_USER_MODEL; if you've changed the value of this
setting after making a migration, be aware that this is not supported. If you
change AUTH_USER_MODEL you must delete and recreate migrations for its app.`. There is no `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in my `settings.py`.

Comment: Remove all half-done migration you could already have from previous django versions, as you could have potentially have migrations from 1.7b3 and newly created migrations that could bite you.

Comment: I checked with by removing all `migrations` directory inside each app also deleted database file. But it showing this error. :(

Comment: Are you using the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE setting for your UserProfile?

If this is the case, it has been deprecated in 1.7, check your settings.

Comment: Then should be other kind of error with your code. Create an empty app/project and try an almost empty models.py referencing "User" and try to narrow the problem somehow :(

Comment: I tried with creating absolutely new project: `$ django-admin.py startproject djtest`, `$ cd djtest`, `$ python manage.py migrate`. Then also getting error. Why don't you try by yourself. **Django should be dev version!**

Answer (score 3):

I read the comment above as suggesting adding only the last line in the dependencies list `(('contenttypes',' __first__'))`, but I had to add the last two to correct the problem. This might be obvious to those with a better understanding of the `makemigrations` tool in Django, but I am new to it and it was not to me.

My last migrations file dependencies list that was originally giving the same error...

```
dependencies = [
    ('myapp', '0006_auto_20150209_0324'),
    (b'auth', b'__first__'),
    (b'contenttypes', b'__first__'),
]
```

Comment: This actually was very useful to me. In my case I have a custom user model, so I didn't need ('auth', '__first__') but my own app + model.

Answer (score 2):

I've found another solution that also work fine.

See the solution of by rockallite.wulf@
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22488

> **Just add the corresponding dependency in the migration file, like this:**
>
> ```
> dependencies = [
>         (b'advperm', b'0001_initial'),
>         (b'auth', b'__first__'),
>         (b'contenttypes', b'__first__'),  # Add this line
> ]
> ```