# ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field default.UserSocialAuth.user: portfolio.User

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I referenced a user model for python-social-auth to portfolio.User where portfolio is the name of my app, and have been encountering this error:

```
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field default.UserSocialAuth.user: portfolio.User
```

I have a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523533/django-valueerror-lookup-failed-for-model-referenced-by-field-account-userprof) question, but I still couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Show more code, provide more context!

Comment: Honestly I was just following the setup instructions here, and the error threw up right after I added the User Model. http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/settings.html

Answer (score 4):

It is reported as bug with Django migrations. Fixed in the new version.

[Django bug tracker ticket #22485](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22485)

[Django bug tracker ticket #22488](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22488)

You need to fix migrations manually for now. Do it by editing dependencies inside the broken migration:

```
dependencies = [
    .
    .
    .
    ('portfolio', '0001_initial'),  # Add this line
]
```

You need to add reference to the missing model.

Try to migrate now, it should work.

Comment: Encountering this issue as well. Any thoughts on how to tell which migrations are the broken ones?

Comment: Unfortunately you need to look for it manually. Look for references to other models like FK or M2M and include the initial migration file into the dependencies if they're not there.