# ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have made Custom User model in my Django project. Here it is:

```
class CustomUser(User):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars')
    about_myself = models.TextField(max_length=300)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def is_author(self):
        return 'blog.change_post' and 'blog.add_post' in self.get_all_permissions()
```

And after it, I changed all Foreign Keys of user to new CustomUser model. It works OK. But I make one new migration and django cause error, when I want to migrate it:

```
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field blog.Comment.author: main.CustomUser
```

My blog.Comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523533/django-valueerror-lookup-failed-for-model-referenced-by-field-account-userprof

Comment: @SimoneZandara I have update Django version, as in this question. But it is not help... It cause `ImportError: cannot import name 'patterns'` now....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the code you posted, you might be might be better served by extending the user model rather than replacing it. This pattern is usually called a profile model and works via a one-to-one relationship with User.

Profiles provides application specific fields and behaviors, while allowing User to go about it's usual business unchanged. It doesn't require you to muck around with rewriting auth or even necessarily change your foreign keys.

Here's an example of your code written as a profile:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # Link to user :
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars')
    about_myself = models.TextField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def is_author(self):
        return 'blog.change_post' and 'blog.add_post' in self.user.get_all_permissions()
```

Comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)

    # How to access the profile:
    def check_author(self):
        self.author.profile.is_author()
```

You'll also want to add a signal to create a new profile when a user is registered:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile(user=instance)
        profile.save()
```

[Django docs on extending users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user).

If a profile approach doesn't work for you, try inheriting from AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser instead of User. The abstract models provide the same basic functionality as User and are the preferred technique for recent Django versions.

There are a handful of additional steps however, check out the [docs on creating custom users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-custom-user-model) for a run down.

Comment: And `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` - what is it? There are not any AUTH_USER_MODEL in my settings.py. From where should I import it? Or can It be built-in User model???

Comment: settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL is a generic way of asking for the currently used User model. Basically to solve a host of issues arising from custom models. It's set to auth.User by default, so it's the same as calling User in your case. It's a good habit to never refer to User directly however, since you (or someone using your code) may decide to make a new model. Check out [referencing the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) for more details.

Comment: To use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your code, simply import `from django.conf import settings`

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? The project I make has not deployed to production, yet. So what I do? Firstly I made model CustomUser and changed all Foreign Keys and other references for it. Then I delete this model and delete all these references. And I create one new model Profile. So, when I will deploy the project to production or someone another will deploy it directly, Is it will be good: install one model and immediately delete it? Can I delete these migrations? And in which way?

Comment: If the project has never been deployed to production and you don't need to retain data locally, you can delete the migrations and create new ones. A better method might be to [squash migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations), which combines a given number migrations into just a few optimized migrations. Be sure to save the original migrations (git, backup), should things don't work out!